# Oracle Apex PL/SQL Function - If all are empty then

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I have a big amount of page items in a Oracle Apex 19 page.

If all of those page items are empty, there should be an error. However, if just one of them is not empty, there should be no error.

I could just create a large if statement, but is there a elegant way to solve this using a PL/SQL function body validation?

Comment: Didn't check, but there could be a method to iterate through all page items. Wouldn't be faster but easier to implement/maintain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could check your items using coalesce:

```
  return coalesce(:P100_DEMO_ITEM1,:P100_DEMO_ITEM2,:P100_DEMO_ITEM3) IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Or concatentation :P100_DEMO_ITEM1||:P100_DEMO_ITEM2